# How can I fix AssertionError (Indent, Dedent) on Statsmodels when switching to another branch?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, statsmodels

I'm running into an assertion error when creating and switched to another branch on git. The origin of the code is the exact same that runs fine without the assertion error. Even when switching back to the original branch, it runs fine without error. How can I fix the AssertionError on the new branch?

- Both branches have the same pasty and statsmodels version.

The traceback most recent call is `model = smf.ols(f'{t} ~ SP50', data=df1).fit()`

The error

```
AssertionError assert token_type not in (tokenize.INDENT, tokenize.DEDENT)
```

```py
def regression_stats():
    df1 = pd.read_csv('source/data_screener/sp_returns.csv')
    total_df = pd.DataFrame()

    for t in tickers:
        model = smf.ols(f'{t} ~ SP50', data=df1).fit()
        beta = model.params['SP50']
        alpha = model.params['Intercept']
        std_errorA = model.bse['Intercept']
        std_errorB = model.bse['SP50']        

        resBeta = pd.DataFrame({f'{t}': beta },index=[0])
        resAlpha = pd.DataFrame({f'{t}': alpha},index=[0])
        resStderrA = pd.DataFrame({f'{t}': std_errorA},index=[0])
        resStderrB = pd.DataFrame({f'{t}': std_errorB},index=[0])

        df_con = pd.concat([resBeta, resAlpha, resStderrA, resStderrB],axis=0)
        total_df = pd.concat([total_df, df_con],axis=1)

    tdf = total_df.transpose()
    tdf.columns = ['Beta', 'Alpha', 'StderrA', 'StderrB']
    tdf.to_csv('source/data_screener/sp_regression.csv')
    print(tdf.round(5))

# stock_prices()
regression_stats()
```

Comment: This error comes from the `patsy` package that `statsmodels` uses under the hood. Check that installations in your environment have not changed. To check versions: `import patsy; print(patsy.__version__)` and `import statsmodels; print(statsmodels.__version__)`.

Comment: The Pasty version and statsmodels version are the same in both branches but I still get the assertion error when switching to the new branch. @AlexK

Comment: This isn't really a Git issue. You just have a Git *hook* (probably a post-checkout hook) that's running some Python and the Python code has a bug in it.

Answer (score -1):

I fixed it by renaming one of my columns in the for loop.